# Is there a way to tell if pyautogui is detecting the color/clicking?

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
SCREEN_SIZE = (1920, 1080)
#define the codec
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
#create the video write object
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (SCREEN_SIZE))
while True:
    #make a screenshot
    img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(680, 785, 560, 20))
    #convert these pixels to a proper numpy array to work with OpenCV
    frame = np.array(img)
    #convert colors from BGR to RGB
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    black = [0,0,0]
    for x in range(img.width):
        for y in range(img.height):
            if img.getpixel((x, y)) == black:
                print(x, y)
                pyautogui.click(x, y)
    #write the frame
    out.write(frame)
    #show the frame
    cv2.imshow("screenshot", frame)
    # if the user clicks q, it exits
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

# make sure everything is closed when exited
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
out.release()
```

I am creating a script to detect black squares, and click them. For some reason when using this, there is no error, but it is not clicking. Is there a way to tell whether it is detecting the color/clicking?

Edit: It does not output the coordinates, and when changing it to print "black" once finding the color, there is still no output.

Comment: Does it print the `x,y` coordinates?

Comment: It does not, there is no output within Jupyter notebook

Comment: That means it isn't detecting the color

Comment: What if the color is definitely within the field of view? Is there a better way to detect for the pixels color?